# Using Certificates with HttpWebRequest in PCL

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library

I've created a Portable Class Library for .NET Framework 4 and Mono.Android, but in HttpWebrequest I can't find ClientCertificates. How can I use ClientCertificates with PCL?

Comment: If I don't recall it wrong, Android does not support client certificates, so you cannot do it.

Comment: Well, it appears it is in both, iOS and Android, so it should be in your project... cah you post the code where you create your request?

Comment: WinPhohe does not support client sertificates, but not Android.

Comment: If I create a Android Library then I will can use ClientCertificates property in HttpWebRequest class, but if I create a PCL library I can't do it.